# Implementing a modular system with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing a modular system to process user input, there are transformers to process correspond raw input, and return transformed data.

```
enum DataType {
  Text = 'TEXT',
  Image = 'IMAGE',
}

// text transformer module

interface TextInput {
  type: DataType.Text,
  text: string
}

interface TextOutput {
  type: DataType.Text,
  text: string
}

const TextTransformer = {
  transform(input: TextInput): TextOutput {
    return {
      type: DataType.Text,
      text: input.text,
    }
  }
}

// image transformer module

interface ImageInput {
  type: DataType.Image,
  url: string
}

interface ImageOutput {
  type: DataType.Image,
  url: string
  width: number
  height: number
}

const ImageTransformer = {
  transform(input: ImageInput): ImageOutput {
    return {
      type: DataType.Image,
      url: input.url,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    }
  }
}

// main module

const transformerMap = {
  [DataType.Text]: TextTransformer,
  [DataType.Image]: ImageTransformer,
}

type Input = TextInput | ImageInput
type Output = TextOutput | ImageOutput

function transform(inputs: Input[]): Output[] {
  return inputs.map(input => {
    const transformer = transformerMap[input.type]
    return transformer.transform(input)
  })
}
```

Now TypeScript will report error on the `transformer.transform(input)` line:

> Argument of type 'Input' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TextInput & ImageInput'.

You can play with the example here:

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpTLAAeCUAvFAOTICiAGslQDT5QCSEcA5lpVewCyAQQDitFrgC+uXAEsQCYACcAZnADGWIqXYh0YMngIIMwAFyxEKMwDodCViZIJLAZwTKF3abIVK1TW0XAHlDAyM2U0xLeCQ0THsXJyglUndPb19cDQB7EA9CF2RlOALVXOUIFQocKNLyyogACgUIywc9CIBKDtDwwzqCAmVgBDBlECHhkzNY6wTgJNIUmbTXKDbDW3XVqBkCGRl5RRV1LQ4uXi7B41S5q3i7Th5gFImAGwyvEB9j-zOQUurzCCAi02iFkeNkSL1472UXygHh+PgIAHc5AATBAAC0s4AgACMVGxccA5NxcRtCSTlNk8gUyHDgCUym4KlUapQ7p52ZyWlsNiybghesDeKDwXcRmMJlMZcNIfMnrCrm82DNPpYhbZPnsMdi8ZYAAwGqDkynU017A77Bn5Qp8xpc5SCODoWp3ADacRhSwcAF0+qQ2S7qsoUr6Fs91cGJayGhymipWMdIRx9INKJ0s2QAD4J0W4DNS7NFUhlgsJquyVRgEAaBByfKpJMC1p5tyWUXewPiqt96ajcaTTZd2xcdCd8HkAB80wIjKd7ZTylqzuTrvd6G9ushgc1UBH8rb-LXO1XVRnhm6bCkd6kQA)

Answer (score 1):

This is classic error.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966710/how-to-get-concrete-type-from-mapping-variable/68967097#68967097) for more context.

`const transformer = transformerMap[input.type]`-> `transformer` variable becomes a union of two funcions:
`(input: TextInput) => TextOutput` and `(input: ImageInput) => ImageOutput`

> multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

Hence, you ended up with `TextInput & ImageInput` which gives you `never` type. This is why you have an error here:

```js
// input is not assignable to never type
return transformer.transform(input)
```

In order to fix it, you need infer each value which is used in function body, I mean `transformerMap` should be passed as a function parameter.

```js
enum DataType {
  Text = 'TEXT',
  Image = 'IMAGE',
}

interface TextInput {
  type: DataType.Text,
  text: string
}

interface TextOutput {
  type: DataType.Text,
  text: string
}

const TextTransformer = {
  transform: (input: TextInput): TextOutput => ({
    type: DataType.Text,
    text: input.text,
  })
}

interface ImageInput {
  type: DataType.Image,
  url: string
}

interface ImageOutput {
  type: DataType.Image,
  url: string
  width: number
  height: number
}

const ImageTransformer = {
  transform: (input: ImageInput): ImageOutput => ({
    type: DataType.Image,
    url: input.url,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  })
}


const transformerMap = {
  [DataType.Text]: TextTransformer,
  [DataType.Image]: ImageTransformer,
}

type Input = TextInput | ImageInput

type Output = TextOutput | ImageOutput

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

const applyTransformer = <
  Key extends typeof DataType,
  Value extends { transform: (arg: Input) => Output },
  TransformMap extends Record<Key & string, Value>>(map: TransformMap) =>
  <
    Type extends keyof TransformMap,
    Inpt extends ({ type: Type }) & Input,
    Inputs extends Inpt[]
  >(inputs: [...Inputs]): Output[] =>
    inputs.map(input => map[input.type].transform(input))

const withTransformer = applyTransformer({
  [DataType.Text]: TextTransformer,
  [DataType.Image]: ImageTransformer,
})

const transformText = withTransformer([{
  type: DataType.Text,
  text: 'string'
}]) // ok


const transformImage = withTransformer([{
  type: DataType.Image,
  url: 'string'
}]) // ok

const _ = withTransformer([{
  type: DataType.Text,
}]) // expected error

const __ = withTransformer([{
  type: DataType.Image,
}]) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpTLAAeCUAvFAOTICiAGslQDT5QCSEcA5lpVewCyAQQDitFrgC+uXAEsQCYACcAZnADGWIqXYh0YMngIIMwAFyxEKMwDodCViZIJLAZwTKF3abIVK1TW0XAHlDAyM2U0xLeCQ0THsXJyglUndPb19cDQB7EA9CF2RlOALVXOUIFQocKNLyyohLAAoFCMsHPQiASk7Q8MMKAD4oFuMCVLNY6wTgJNIU53SodsNbNMc2KR7s-xV1LQ4uXm6hieiLK3i7Th5gFLBlABsMrxAfGXlFA6Dj+7CCAidRM02uNkSd14jxebyyBAA7nIACYIAAWlnAEAARio2GjgHJuGjXFAsbjlNk8gUyFDgCUym4KlUapQLg0mU1WmtSXSzgg+v9eIDgeRRuM2KCYuC5rY6UsoE9Xqt9OslQqkaiMVAAAwKglEkmWPXbXZfHL5QqeRnM6rKQRwdC1CYAbTiEPmDgAuv1SAzGizlCk3bNbidgD6hfSObaVKwvpcOKqyJQusmoAAfKP82SJkVDVMDIFDLN0-MIXNmKAANTgzzAwDcAB5kKNUy6ANbAVC5VSEL2yamFR3oZ6of2cwO1JtsADS3agLlAyLcU0wvZlZhStfrWCXIBXOFSMa5Yzgym4ln5PRGUHLUCkKQntodTv3h4ASsA8spkU356gUAAGRQB47zcMwNZ1g2wzDC0XDoJ0J5VK+N5imwM6TIQVbvquXY9n2z5NK+CrdGQuFjNga5XHMD43iB-Kkcmq4UWRLoDgQcE8m4lgurY-H8m4XqCuW7EjJKKoRG4tgIW06ZilACEujyGxmF6GzIRAcm9LsFo0lASLokRU6UCOY7GXaEoECGNyJN6voIBZcZsDZHpyuGkZ0k5QbSLpQ5kNaAYQA4tSGWi3ktC6Fxgu6soOCkmyWFQYHeFQ0jCVAAD0mVQLkHayHpVqaXSoVyEZmkqJF0XSrFYb3DCyrJZkHxpVIGXZbl+WFWQAD6pXlTaTSVVFUQxaGdnJOlN4dSQmAaEoyKLsoyiVIOlq9X1lBhRFI1SlctWQuG8btTls3fgtS0rcoQA)

You can find more information in my blog [here](https://catchts.com/react-props) and [here](https://catchts.com/mutations)

If you are interested in function arguments infering see [this](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) article.

Comment: then I need to call transform with: `transform(transformerMap)([])` right? But it still gets typescript error in the playgroud

Comment: Thanks! But isn't it work because of the `any` in `transform: (arg: any) => any`? I think I can get the same result if I add `transformer.transform(input as any)` in my code

Comment: Yes, but as you might have noticed I also added few constraint for the arguments, basically you can call this function with wrong arguments. There is a way to type it without type assertion but then you will end up with several condition statements or redundant runtime checks. Give me some time I will show you

Comment: I ended up with a bit unreadable typings but seems to be it works. Please let me know