# Is there a better way to tell typescript which type "data" is?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm following an action/reducer pattern for React [put forth by Kent Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) and I'm trying to add some type safety to it.

```
export type Action = 
    { type: "DO_SOMETHING", data: { num: Number } } |
    { type: "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE", data: { nums: Number[] } };

type Actions = {
    [key in Action["type"]]: (state: State, data: Action["data"]) => State;
};

const actions: Actions = {
   DO_SOMETHING: (state, data) => {
       return { nums: [data.num] }; // Type error
   },
   DO_SOMETHING_ELSE: (state, data) => {
       return { nums: data.nums }; // Type error
   }
};
```

This code is nice because it ensures the `actions` object contains all the action types listed in the `Action` union type as well as providing type safety when trying to dispatch an action. The problem comes in when trying to access members of `data`.

```
Property 'num' does not exist on type '{ num: Number; } | { nums: Number[]; }'.
  Property 'num' does not exist on type '{ nums: Number[]; }'.
```

But, if I do this:

```
export type Action = 
    { type: "DO_SOMETHING", data: { num: Number } } |
    { type: "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE", data: { nums: Number[] } };

type Actions = {
    [key in Action["type"]]: (state: State, action: Action) => State;
};

const actions: Actions = {
   DO_SOMETHING: (state, action) => {
       if (action.type !== "DO_SOMETHING") return state;
       return { nums: [action.data.num] }; // No more type error
   },
   DO_SOMETHING_ELSE: (state, action) => {
       if (action.type !== "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE") return state;
       return { nums: action.data.nums }; // No more type error
   }
};
```

Now TypeScript knows `action.data` is the union type that matches the explicit `action.type`. Is there a cleaner way to do this without having to inline all the actions into a big switch statement?

PS - Here is [the full playground snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgCb5pJTZFIDCEAdjEgB5aKoYByEpScAL5wAZlAgg4AIihcYUgNwAoJQHpVcAOoALFPBjbghOIRh6BAGwgQA1sYvAbSAHRK2kWHBgBPMAIDKZixwALy4SnCRcIz4IIQAXHDcsQBGVADaALpKgspKaEymcMCMwDDAKBaB5onVwWE4EVExcYlZOXnqWrrw6OWFcCiygwBuKMAWKCkWLm6sHvq+AgCCGMBMoXBNkXg+folSACIA8gD6-scAsgCiACoAEgCS3ADiUtikeiiJeC2JySA0lAhCCAD7bXBeJYHE7nK53J6vU7XAAy-mu7zgnzMP2isQSSVSGUyINyKj2KzWAwaEPSAGliow4Kt+ox0lIKVJMplEgAKUw1OB1JAfL6Ja7sKB9AA8LPWjGwu2hcAZggAfOzsSguQBKUJqoVBJDKMn5Qq9KmMAly6nhKKwi43B7PF58gUsUVmPUhA2NKL+2QwfBQJm-fFtLXOFokslRQSYbYO+HOpGo9Fuo2elDe30QqKB4OhvGtLFfKP4oTKOMdFQFK3wBjMNjwMLIPrONCycyNljsaUQv3+qLupC1I1VoeRUhGMB6NDaPl9eWJG2MHNwEYQYCkCHCUEERj8EQlJA7tW8-CHpDHxinnV5ESXy1wWTkSjA-lGsfmbBLpgry0dW-YJB0iOsilvAB3YVNj-K10jg5wKUyT8f0GS1nC1e8IQLENIWcAiR2wAioyQaCjUrHIVHcaB4EfRhn0OJBCGAABzRhLiQGJhQABXEEZtyoXkcHnCZSFkRhBB+USLHErjEjbHg+CQQQ9VAuBwPgdIiKxGc520EkwloMgKCE19TOoRkygqKojWw-1NI3Sp8AEBodOnQhZxgedY3zJAgzw3k8yiaUe2bZw+IgAT+GBMYLBckIcDilz1WCycRMMWSJMENK4GlVQwvYCL+MEqA1QhbCcrmBZRCfVkCGIJiWPYzjuKNXk1IhRy617FsGvoJhet5QqYHsqJgBEOBeR65tQhCIyrxvO87UnLxtHESDojIuBrigcQoF5KRaCatiOK4-AYJAIh4DSfrSDgSCykMJkUDgE6WvO3iSpiqQxsiHKA38wsNMG5sTSAA) I've been using to test all this.

Comment: Do your actions have a consistent top struct of these two keys: `{ type: string; data: any }`?

Comment: FYI it looks like you’re recreating a lot of the logic of @reduxjs/toolkit, so maybe you can use that.  It has very strong types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close.

This line `Action['data']` in `(state: State, data: Action["data"]) => State;` was incorrect.

`Action['data']` should have been binded with `key` property.

See this example:

```js
type State = {
    nums: number[]
}
export type Action =
    | { type: "DO_SOMETHING", data: { num: number } }
    | { type: "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE", data: Pick<State, 'nums'> };

type Actions = {
    [Type in Action["type"]]: (state: State, data: Extract<Action, { type: Type }>['data']) => State;
};

const actions: Actions = {
    DO_SOMETHING: (state, data) => ({ nums: [data.num] }),
    DO_SOMETHING_ELSE: (state, data) => ({ nums: data.nums })
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQVtQHYFcBbAZwC48iAjCAJwG0BdDAXwwgA8wB7G4KUSFACCAY2ABLLrijIsOAD7p%204COQBEAEQDyAfRhaAsgFEAKgAkAkgDkA4moA0UACaJ45NBULkChajSjMAXLYih4CqlCauvrG5tY2OkYAMjBGDs6u5AAK4iIA1gA8cIgQjgDkPsRlAHwBANwYGOHCYpK4xDLowVB0JipQ4tKiElJ0auFqDAzkABTECEjkxUiOLgjkRuzANPBiBcNtjmEq5H2CzNV0ZWvwZQwAlDK1yxANzA0YIlLzULsj7eQDt9OpgcFBtHpDKZLLZZvMSqtXI9kLUZh5KuQ6DcAHQ%20BgBe72boQmLQ%20KJFJGOELUoZBDI1HoohkOnwXHMgksOpAA)

I have used `Type` instead of `key` since we are iterating through `types` property.

`Extract` - expects two arguments. First - a union, second - type it should match. Treat it as an `Array.prototype.filter` for unions.

P.S. Please avoid using constructor types like `Number`, use `number` instead.

Interface `Number` corresponds to number as an object and `Number` as a class corresponds to class constructor:

```js
interface Number {
    toString(radix?: number): string;
    toFixed(fractionDigits?: number): string;
    toExponential(fractionDigits?: number): string;
    toPrecision(precision?: number): string;
    valueOf(): number;
}

interface NumberConstructor {
    new(value?: any): Number;
    (value?: any): number;
    readonly prototype: Number;
    readonly MAX_VALUE: number;
    readonly MIN_VALUE: number;
    readonly NaN: number;
    readonly NEGATIVE_INFINITY: number;
    readonly POSITIVE_INFINITY: number;
}

declare var Number: NumberConstructor;
```

**UPDATE**

Code snippet taken from your shared example:

```js
function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    
    /**
     * Argument of type '{ num: Number; } | { nums: Number[]; }'
     *  is not assignable to parameter of type '{ num: Number; } & { nums: Number[]; }'.
     */
    const newState = actions[action.type](state, action.data);
    return { ...state, ...newState };
}
```

You are getting this error because:

> multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

Hence, second argument of `actions[action.type]` function is an intersection of all arguments of `Actions`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966710/how-to-get-concrete-type-from-mapping-variable/68967097#68967097) you have an answer with more examples and [here](https://catchts.com/react-props) you can read my article.

You can add condition statement:

```js
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
    if(action.type==="DO_SOMETHING"){
        const newState = actions[action.type](state, action.data); // ok
    }
// ....
}
```

But this is bad solution because you have a lot of actions. This is not how we handle it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176666/implementing-a-modular-system-with-typescript/69177072#69177072) you can find similar example.

So you have two options, except the previous.

First one, just use type assertion - `as` and move on.

Second one:

```js
type Builder<A extends { type: PropertyKey, data: any }> = {
    [K in A["type"]]: (state: State, data: Extract<A, { type: K }>["data"]) => State;
};


const reducer = <
    Type extends PropertyKey,
    Data,
    Act extends { type: Type, data: Data },
    Acts extends Builder<Act>
>(actions: Acts) =>
    (state: State, action: Act): State => {
        const newState = actions[action.type](state, action.data);
        return { ...state, ...newState };
    }
```

As you might have noticed I have infered each property of `Action` and made strict relationship between `actions` and `action`.

[Full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgCb5pJTZFIDCEAdjEgB5aKoYByEpScAL5wAZlAgg4AIihcYUgNwAoJQHpVcAOoALFPBjbghOIRh6BAGwgQA1sYvAbSAHRK2kWHBgBPMAIDKZixwALy4SnCRcIz4IIQAXHDcsQBGVADaALpKgspKaEymcMCMwDDAKBaB5onVwWE4EVExcYlZOXnqWrrw6OWFcCiygwBuKMAWKCkWLm6sHvq%20AgCCGMBMoU2ReD5%20iVIAIgDyAPr%20RwCyAKIAKgASAJLcAOJS2KR6KIl4LYnJIGkoEJgQAfLa4LxLfbHM6XW6PF4nK4AGX8VzecA%20Zm%200ViCSSqQymWBuRUuwEACF8BN%20FAADzLOBsFiMUjGHZQuAABXEflg3gA0khvO9PokUIxvEIAHyhcJRODpAXFRhwZbpKTkqSZTKJAAUphqcDqSFF2LgV3YUD6DOwHL2cGVgmlGqxKG1AEpQrKTcpSUpyWq1gMwlSaVQGcHGNKVAVGEU%20ut44lVv143LGgqYedrvcns99YaWGaUF6QrLMwqorIYPgoKqfni2m7nC1iaSFYJMODs3C84iUWjC0FTZjPmWK%20CFTW6w3ca0x2ZW3ihMpOx1Y4V4AxmMy5cg%20s40LJzDuWOw6eDK1WTCPaiO1zfMUYwHo0Np9YmmCmoxO4CMIGAUhwWEEECFZJARBKJBgOlPV8AgqDGBgj08nyLc4FkchKCBMJLwVG4liZdgkFZYweQgPkfCFEUe0%20bsFVTYiWTZCFyUSQi-BLRIDk%20IQGKiVNjGZUjWLDCxaUjGAYzgr9kyDGBCAncEDTvY0R2wOSfxgD173Mb15SfOMimQgB3E05Tkwh0jk5xyUyVTzE0qNnDdVCp2rJBa3rCFnD8otRz81skHMkdVxAlR3GgeARAQqM4AOJBCGAABzRgLlI-ATQokYgKoPU8HfGlZFVQQcSKiSSsSA8eD4ARBC9a84GM%20B0gC94XzfbRiTCWgyAofKsIGqA9Ssj1sBKMoKiqEd3IVFr-0qfABAaW8nOfQhXxgd9wunLzZzgPUPMiOkz2ZZwcryoExgsZaQhwG7ludY6qxwCrSBKwQXrpVQzvYC7xFy2kYwVdyvrmBZRDitMCGIRLkrSjKYhNPVGvBBa43PeBeuIP6YD1PG5qiYAREOzG9xCSnwP4JCUMMm8DHEUzohCi0oHEEapFoeHUvSzKLJAIh4DSWGYLgUyykMVUUASpLeaRrKR0u2kpCJyIvr27zVXJ9g-SAA)

P.S. `reducer` is curried, so don't forget to pass it as `reducer(actions)` to `useReducer`.

Comment: You also should probably take into account @Linda Paiste's comment

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. One follow-up question if you don't mind. Any idea how to resolve this bit now? https://i.imgur.com/7cFqKOW.png Also I sadly don't have the choice to use Redux or I would XD, oh and I hear ya on "Number", it was merely a typo.

Comment: I've added the full typescript playground snippet I've been using to the question (URL too long for this comment and shortened URLs apparently aren't allowed)

Comment: @Chev made an update. Btw, there is a plugin in ts playground which you can use for url shortening

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Saved me from type hell.

Answer (score 1):

```
type ActionDataMap = {
    DO_SOMETHING: { num: Number };
    DO_SOMETHING_ELSE: { nums: Number[] } 
};

type ActionType = keyof ActionDataMap
type ActionsMap = {
  [K in ActionType]: { type: K; data: ActionDataMap[K] }
}

// this will generate the union:
type Action = ActionsMap[ActionType]

// you can index into ActionsMap with K to find the specific Action
type Actions = {
    [K in ActionType]: (state: State, action: ActionsMap[K]) => State;
};
```

Comment: The other answer was more complete but honorable mention to you good sir. I adopted this ActionDataMap pattern as well.

Comment: Sure. His answer is more educational, I learn sth too. I wasn’t aware of the `Extract` builtin type before. But in real-life scenario I think my answer is more practical in terms of readability and imposes less workload on TS type checker.