# Typescript does not understand that record types must return the correct type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

Sorry for the difficult title, but please take a look at the following minimal representation:

```js
// We define a couple of symbols
const A: unique symbol = Symbol();
const B: unique symbol = Symbol();

// And create an "enum" of them
const Fs = {
  A,
  B
} as const;

// This is the type A | B
type F = typeof Fs[keyof typeof Fs];

// This is our "input" types
type Foo = {
  [Fs.A]: string,
  [Fs.B]: number,
}

// This is our "output" types
type Bar = {
  [Fs.A]: number,
  [Fs.B]: string,
}

// We define a Mapping for the key (A or B) to be a function taking an
// input of type defined in Foo, and spitting out an output of type defined in Bar
type Mapping<T extends F> = (arg: Foo[T]) => Bar[T];

// We then define a map record as being a list of all such functions
type MapRecord = {
  [key in F]: Mapping<key>
}

// Here is the action mapping. It does indeed comply with map record.
const mappings: MapRecord = {
  [Fs.A]: (arg: string) => 123,
  [Fs.B]: (arg: number) => "asdf",
} as const;

// And here we execute the mapping. Can you spot the error?
function doMapping<T extends F>(t: T, arg: Foo[T]): Bar[T] {
  const mapper: Mapping<T> = mappings[t];
  return mapper(arg);
}
```

Seems perfectly fine. But on that `const mapper...` line, we actually get the following error:

```
Type 'Mapping<unique symbol> | Mapping<unique symbol>' is not assignable to type 'Mapping<T>'.
  Type 'Mapping<unique symbol>' is not assignable to type 'Mapping<T>'.
    Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible.
      Type 'Foo[T]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

It seems to think that the result of `mapping[t]` could be any of the possible records, when we *know* that it has to be just one.

Why? And how do I convince typescript otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few side notes:

**First:**

```js
const mappings: MapRecord = {
  [Fs.A]: (arg: string) => 123,
  [Fs.B]: (arg: number) => "asdf",
} as const;
```

Don't use explicit type `MapRecord` with `as const`. `mappings` will be infered as `MapRecord`. `as const` does not affect the type of `mappings` at all. Hence, you need to apply one or another bot not both.

**Second:**

The main problem is in this line: `mappings[t]`. `mappings[t]` returns a union of functions. When you want to call a union of functions, their arguments are intersected. Hence you are getting `number & string === never`. Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred:

Please see related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966710/how-to-get-concrete-type-from-mapping-variable/68967097#68967097), [article](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2), [article](https://catchts.com/react-props)

---

In order to infer mappings an allow it, you should also pass `mappings` as an argument. I usually `curry` it.

You can use this approach:

```js
// We define a couple of symbols
const A: unique symbol = Symbol();
const B: unique symbol = Symbol();

// And create an "enum" of them
const Fs = {
    A,
    B
} as const;


// This is our "input" types
type Foo = {
    [Fs.A]: string,
    [Fs.B]: number,
}

// This is our "output" types
type Bar = {
    [Fs.A]: number,
    [Fs.B]: string,
}

// Here is the action mapping. It does indeed comply with map record.
const mappings = {
    [Fs.A]: (arg: string) => 123,
    [Fs.B]: (arg: number) => "asdf",
} as const;


// This is the type A | B
type F = typeof Fs[keyof typeof Fs];

const doMapping = <
    Key extends symbol,
    Value extends (arg: any) => any, // MAIN DRAWBACK
    Mapping extends Record<Key, Value>
>(mapping: Mapping) =>
    <
        Type extends keyof Mapping,
        >(type: Type, arg: Parameters<Mapping[Type]>[0]): ReturnType<Mapping[Type]> =>
        mapping[type](arg)

const result = doMapping(mappings)(Fs.A, 's') // number
const result2 = doMapping(mappings)(Fs.B, 42) // number

const error = doMapping(mappings)(Fs.B, 'a') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFNQE0gzAlgO2gQ1AYwPYFcAOANtNvKAM4CeAtgEbaHkBQOy5ALqAIIBcouyRAEdc0KnQagAvKADKNeoQAUASgDcLbG04AhPgOGiKCyTPkTl6pkxDdkMLACdIadumSgARJGS5qn0FJQdgALSGpNbVAAMXJpUABvJlAU7gAaZNSdJgBfUDQ41g4Na1sAFRDEOKrA3EcvFHxcdgD2SnxIZjaOmOxseKTU0ABtWIA6LgBdPg5HFABzDKHR8jGdadBfOkhHDJzSsAqamrx6zzx2Jpbg9s6mbugdNHqZQdSViY2t2h2l9-H1jN2HNkItcgdQAAJHbQGqhdCYdiILSgahofD4BZjUAASU4MGwnVAKDgkAcOGoREooAA7ohQqj0aBnDhHDAxpEOIyMQs4q9MikPlM%20EpnvMgSD5ippAA%20UAARgATABmP6CgEbUWOcWbPw-RzSqRyzwFGDwTx7fKFLTFaw2Q6VapxeE3HpcUAAH1A2QeMXiDyCsWGAGtIJQggGyLFJiUivjsABZdGY0HxAA8AtAAGkw6BIAAPNz2OLiRRq0AANTQhCMBaLMDiWp1aGQlENcpblDSoFsCa4OIAcqAACIAJS44B0XAAwlnM0meam6z4G6BR5BWTA0zmu5Xq6IZUwZUo0YudQuU1LZZmM0MhmVbnnCyu4qHw2QLwty0Njw8%20A%20Om7MU%20AABWeNBqEgNxHHINNP1BYYAMgSYZWGAAGSYVD4dd2DqZAkLg5MFkQ24UOvO9UlPS9hgeSYmxUaw42ZTpcEITgZAJeD5hPIjQXIFQlHGLhuwAcnIETpVsb4dk5ThnHIVj2EVeJON47iqN5ASAW7AAWRVJLAaTHEYm1OB2RxsBeWBEzUniz34wTVh0US0AknswALDpETJPNHAsxwgA)

**`Key`** - is infered key of main argument
**`Value`** - is infered function
**`Mapping`** - is infered argument.

As you might have noticed it is similar to how we destructure JS objects. In `similar` way it is possible to infer them. The algorithm: infer each nested key and value and then assemble them into one data structure.

**`Type`** - infered first argument with appropriate constraint

You can find more information about function arguments inference in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#first_level_inference)

Personally, I think safest approach is just return a function:

```js
// We define a couple of symbols
const A: unique symbol = Symbol();
const B: unique symbol = Symbol();

// And create an "enum" of them
const Fs = {
    A,
    B
} as const;


// This is our "input" types
type Foo = {
    [Fs.A]: string,
    [Fs.B]: number,
}

// This is our "output" types
type Bar = {
    [Fs.A]: number,
    [Fs.B]: string,
}

// Here is the action mapping. It does indeed comply with map record.
const mappings = {
    [Fs.A]: (arg: string) => 123,
    [Fs.B]: (arg: number) => "asdf",
} as const;

type Mappings = typeof mappings

const doMapping = <Type extends keyof Mappings,>(type: Type) =>
    mappings[type]

const result = doMapping(Fs.A) // (arg:string)=>number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFNQE0gzAlgO2gQ1AYwPYFcAOANtNvKAM4CeAtgEbaHkBQOy5ALqAIIBcouyRAEdc0KnQagAvKADKNeoQAUASgDcLbG04AhPgOGiKCyTPkTl6pkxDdkMLACdIadumSgARJGS5qn0FJQdgALSGpNbVAAMXJpUABvJlAU7gAaZNSdJgBfUDQ41g4Na1sAFRDEOKrA3EcvFHxcdgD2SnxIZjaOmOxseKTU0ABtWIA6LgBdPg5HFABzDKHR8jGdadBfOkhHDJzSsAqamrx6zzx2Jpbg9s6mbugdNHqZQdSViY2t2h2l9-H1jN2HNkItcgdQAAJHbQGqhdCYdiILSgahofD4BZjUAASU4MGwnVAKDgkAcOGoREooAA7ohQqj0aBnDhHDAxpEOIyMQs4q9MikPlM%20EpnvMgSD5ippAA%20UAARgATABmP6CgEbUWOcWbPw-RzSqRyzwFGDwTx7fKFLTFawPUAAWXRmNBfJuHSCaJ5rusRXx2Cd3vm8QAPGVbqBIAAPNz2OIAa0glCCgZd83IaRlSgefHDHUNMoF3LT5GGD0mvptnGc5FwhE4MgJqYWSnGXGltm%20OyYQA)

Easy and simple.