# How to use Typescript generics to correctly map between keys and values with indirection?

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to write a strongly typed mapper that will map indirectly using one object's values to pick methods matching another object's keys.

The actual `mapper` in the code below is not mine, it's external and javascript based. Since I cannot modify this, I have implemented a typed wrapper called `mapTyped` in the code below.

This is the best attempt I've managed to do, based on other sources found on the topic.

It performs well on the following goals

- ensures matching function definitions between `Repository` and `MappedFunctions`
- prevents writing the wrong name as lookup, for example `mapTyped<MappedFunctions>()({baz: "bazIntrnal"})` will give a compiler error due to spelling
- works perfectly if only one item is provided in the map, the function arguments and return type will be correctly inferred

**However, it does not work if I provide more than one item in the map.**

Then all the mapped functions will have a union of all the mapped functions' definitions.

**How do I modify `mapTyped` so that it will return unique values per "row" in the Record matching the key?** (and not a union of values as it is now)

See the comments in the minimal repro code below, [and here's a playground that demonstrates my issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFtg5UA7AEwCcBTOQmrOYSATxjoFoAzByMGwAbQtmDEAhpTKFMNfHWAA3ScMw9CvXFVyQ4AKA5dQANTUaA8rwA8l7ACs6+SABVOdADRmLddyboAD0g6ajhQAGs6di1QeycXfzpQAF5I6Nj45zcPAD5UuMdspIBtc3U-DwBdAG4DIw9QAFk6DEIqJIKAClxeyRpkRFBJCnYSqoBKVPyR9jrjZIAlOhhCckgmdgLlohoqGzhIGkpkbxa2jry6gxBh4WFh1VRhSRFk3kwKF1RCCkMiP6QUAfL6QH5-BCgZardabUAAMmakhgXCoADFPt9fuE0gBvAygYGEQgASQoIRoFDUkK6vGJAEEBpCKJhiNg6DQpil8gBGUAAaiJhEZpwJoGw-TJFKpwhpEpoIshh2OFGQXPyACJ5YrQBqBeL+iLPGKJQAvKUcmVyySmnXYYnCOgjdWgEoaxjEOga7wa-o0STsb26gDu6HAQbNIqqBgAvvVbnIaKApCi6FRgZiwdiGiYmsjURjQeCcaB8YS6aTyZbqaBaQymaAWWyOS6m+yaMbCWaLZSa11Iw37YRHc7prXlScAD5DkcUCbjWPxsAprhJulJv0B0BMbdFFygG5gLqSFyYNSgVDEGCOz3kyRZigX8JBaXnjbJrYwGiEBJAkbpklQHIK9hC2YMRiBd9g2OEJhlABZ02g-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-nmY5W2VYNU1OYHZBIXl438hls2LZT62lbZ8tiTV+sk8bKPBZNzWY7jH2w+q1IDAY25XAACRJcqHcsRYGtKsUQF6XAUxK9bkPRTNiyuiYulxDndW7Kte2EDUYwmTtQAb5vyrRekSVxrvCV7-uMsH1Nh6LbEx4nqetRtHsZSDCtIQ1Ctr7UBel7FYPQ4uCOTYAFgAJlja4CZMCwGAUMN0ZogwP2JJA9+NB6Yah0phbEw46C4FEMgLoWQXC4AGnAAi1c4AyUAWAOQID9CQjdB6L0PpNyBh9KGDAQYjgaEQbcbAwDQBoGUAweCz4aDfhoDSL8hBVwcCmFPY8Ax-LMjoNw0u+QBYW3Tiqc2csraK1SiKVk9ltwCQWKAAA5FnAxT5Gw02GHAcgyAqRvHgoQUAMB+iSF9ihWI+iDEUFkRyAxuAui-wAMzfwAKwYSwigtBhAMG+1JnAXAZoujMLoEQgwQA).

```
// https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/value-of.d.ts
type ValueOf<ObjectType, ValueType extends keyof ObjectType = keyof ObjectType> = ObjectType[ValueType];

type MethodType = (...args: any[]) => any;
type Repository = Record<string, MethodType>;

// all available functions
const functions: Repository & MappedFunctions = {
  fooInternal: (fooArg: number) => 1 + fooArg,
  barInternal: (barArg: string) => "barArg: " + barArg,
  bazInternal: (bazArg: boolean) => ["some", "array", "with", bazArg]
}

// our mapped functions
type MappedFunctions = {
  fooInternal: (fooArg: number) => number,
  bazInternal: (bazArg: boolean) => (string|boolean)[]
}

// mapper for array or object 
// (actual implementation is external to my project and I simply want to write a typed wrapper for it)
const mapper = (map: Record<string, string>|string[]) => {
  const ret: Repository = {};
  if (Array.isArray(map)) {
    map.forEach(m => ret[m] = functions[m]);
  } else {
    Object.entries(map).forEach(m => ret[m[0]] = functions[m[1]]);
  }
  return ret;
}

// my typed mapper wrapper
function mapTyped<S extends Record<SK, SM>, SK extends string = keyof S & string, SM extends MethodType = MethodType>():
  <M extends Record<MK, SK>, MK extends string = string>(
  map: M
) => {
  [K in ValueOf<M> as keyof M]: S[K];
} { return (map: any) => mapper(map) as any; }

// ACTUAL:
// const methods: {
//     otherMethod: () => number;
//     baz: ((fooArg: number) => number) | ((bazArg: boolean) => (string | boolean)[]);
//     foo: ((fooArg: number) => number) | ((bazArg: boolean) => (string | boolean)[]);
// }
// EXPECTED:
// const methods: {
//     otherMethod: () => number;
//     baz: ((bazArg: boolean) => (string | boolean)[]);
//     foo: ((fooArg: number) => number);
// }
const methods =
{
  // THIS WORKS
  //...mapTyped<MappedFunctions>()({baz: "bazInternal"}),
  // THIS FAILS
  ...mapTyped<MappedFunctions>()({baz: "bazInternal", foo: "fooInternal"}),
  otherMethod: () => 42
};

// outputs: ["baz", "foo", "otherMethod"] 
console.log(Object.keys(methods));

// outputs: ["some", "array", "with", true] 
// but gives ts error: (property) baz: (arg0: never) => number | (string | boolean)[]
// Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
console.log(methods.baz(true));
```

EDIT: **SOLUTION** thanks to the answer by @captain-yossarian this is the final code I ended up using for the typed mapper

```
const mapTyped = <
  S extends Record<keyof S & string, MethodType>,
  Keys extends keyof S & string = keyof S & string,
>() => {
  function anonymous<Prop extends string, Mp extends Record<Prop, Keys>>(map: Mp): {
    [P in Keys as GetKeyByValue<Mp, P>]: S[P]
  }
  function anonymous<Prop extends string, Mp extends Record<Prop, Keys>>(map: Mp) {
    return mapper(map)
  }
  return anonymous
}
```

.. [and an updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFtg5UA7AEwCcBTOQmrOYSATxjoFoAzByMGwAbQtmDEAhpTKFMNfHWAA3ScMw9CvXFVyQ4AKA5dQANTUaA8rwA8l7ACs6%20SABVOdADRmLddyboAD0g6ajhQAGs6di1QeycXfzpQAF5I6Nj45zcPAD5UuMdspIBtc3U-DwBdAG4DIw9QAFk6DEIqJIKAClxeyRpkRFBJCnYSqoBKVPyR9jrjZIAlOhhCckgmdgLlohoqGzhIGkpkbxa2jry6gxBh4WFh1VRhSRFk3kwKF1RCCkMiP6QUAfL6QH5-BCgZardabUAAMmakhgXCoADFPt9fuE0gBvAygYGEQgASQoIRoFDUkK6vGJAEEBpCKJhiNg6DQpil8gBGUAAaiJhEZpwJoGw-TJFKpwhpEpoIshh2OFGQXPyACJ5YrQBqBeL%20iLPGKJQAvKUcmVyySmnXYYnCOgjdWgEoaxjEOga7wa-o0STsb26gDu6HAQbNIqqBgAvvVbnIaKApCi6FRgZiwdiGiYmsjURjQeCcaB8YS6aTyZbqaBaQymaAWWyOS6m%20yaMbCWaLZSa11Iw37YRHc7prXlScAD5DkcUCbjWPxsAprhJulJv0B0BMbdFFygG5gLqSFyYNSgVDEGCOz3kyRZigX8JBaXnjbJrYwGiEBJAkbpklQHIK9hC2YMRiBd9g2OEJhlABZ02g-MOSJJN0AmAwAUOZNkKTNIuhTSEdiYfYJ1VbwyOQXJJ0o8YXTLUAsKBehICIlY1nQOE8RjOpCVQXha0Zf12FwVA4CEgMCORCYpgYwkU1wdcAFET3AAixxYkpiCqAoQSxP4tMmXjQBjUA6GEOBkjkwpf1wUIjlQBgpJgCZFKYFT8DU4gNNaLSSgABiqHS0j0h84D8nkgomYy40JFj5EfFi6jjHNkgAcVaABpaIACF2HKDQ7EcbwCrofI8TFEoAAVvxgC9HyiGIBPiKpIXiarap0l9QiocJStAAB%20UAasIOrmToZQOVjEpGsyRxo0PD94I8dMVxQpDUxoTDsSBFMknTNIbDFABlMzgh68JiL2GxZoE07EUos5WnAdoklyTtQGy9hn3OsJ0ia0B7qAhzVQKW7AYRYGVVFXIunosVQvBYYKF%20dhiDkOAbBGurur%20x7mhx37eqhZwSKx2rvC%20uBclhwiCYmSFrOq%20rPuicJJHCDLIC%20vLSpsJoYG8KrclawHqujQlYozItfmR1H0cwTHsbOkI8ZB04CZVi6Sd2fZscptmaecyEBdksU4taBKcM25yMMlsV4spOXRgVwwUqY5NnvaHEDAY3pcD2lb%20eQ9FM2LWGJi6XEzUhLUbR7GUgwrWOKwTtQNRjCYPsIDAOXOF6qBpF0ABYACZY2uBNMFgauhjdM0gw1CtG5z8A869qgNR07a-mHOhcFEZAuiyFxcEauACI7uAZMrsA5Br-RITdD0vR9TdAx9UMMCDI4NG7rC%204Hwgh89C44FwM0ul3ugZ4MIA)

BONUS: [This is a gist of the code that uses this typed wrapper for Vuex 4 and Vue 3](https://gist.github.com/joakimriedel/7aab32e9e69361241fc84e34d2eafab7).

Comment: You are receiving `arg0: never` because if you want to call a function which has a type of function union it merges (intersects) all arguments. Hence, if your arguments are `string` and `number` - you are receiving `string & number === never`. See related question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629222/typescript-does-not-understand-that-record-types-must-return-the-correct-type/69629742#69629742  . Could you please minimize your example and explicitly comment an errors

Comment: Second thing, you should be aware of is mutation. Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631285/how-to-assert-matching-types-when-iterating-over-an-object/69631394#69631394 . If you want to make it type safe, dont mutate your values like here `ret[m] = functions[m]`

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarian, 1) yes I know this but the merging of all arguments is the problem, hence my question - I would like the values to be unique in the record matched with the key, not a union as it is now 2) the mapper is not mine, it's external (and javascript, not typescript) and I want to wrap it with a typed version - I've just added a simple hack here of the function to build a minimal example of the problem

Comment: As for the gist. Good job. I' m not familiar with Vue but it is looks like you have typed everything ;)

Comment: I just put it in a huge Vue/Vuex project today, and thanks to the use of strict types I could find 20+ bugs just by compiling the project!  Typescript is fantastic, but I wouldn't have been able to put together a solution like yours even if I had the related answers just in front of me so - thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see related answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643682/either-type-containing-different-types/69644729#69644729) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629222/typescript-does-not-understand-that-record-types-must-return-the-correct-type/69629742#69629742)

Now, hover the mouse over `methods.baz`. You will see that `baz` method is a union of two functions:
`((fooArg: number) => number) | ((bazArg: boolean) => (string | boolean)[])`.

If you read related answers, you know that calling a function which is a union of several functions causes arguments intersection.

In your case, it is `number & boolean === never`.

Let's start from `mapper`.

I think it is worth splitting `mapper` into two strategies `mapperArray` and `mapperObject`:

```js
const functions = {
  fooInternal: (fooArg: number) => 1 + fooArg,
  barInternal: (barArg: string) => "barArg: " + barArg,
  bazInternal: (bazArg: boolean) => ["some", "array", "with", bazArg]
} as const

type FunctionsKeys = keyof typeof functions;

type MappedFunctions = {
  fooInternal: (fooArg: number) => number,
  bazInternal: (bazArg: boolean) => (string | boolean)[]
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type MethodType = (...args: any[]) => any;
type Repository = Record<string, MethodType>;

const mapperArray = <Elem extends FunctionsKeys, Elems extends Elem[]>(map: [...Elems]) =>
  map.reduce<Repository>((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: functions[elem]
  }), {})

const mapperObject = <
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  Value extends FunctionsKeys
>(map: Record<Key, Value>) =>
  (Object.entries(map) as Array<[Key, Value]>)
    .reduce<Repository>((acc, elem) => ({
      ...acc,
      [elem[0]]: functions[elem[1]]
    }), {})

const mapper = <Key extends FunctionsKeys>(map: Record<string, Key> | Key[]) =>
  Array.isArray(map)
    ? mapperArray(map)
    : mapperObject(map)
```

I know, that `mapper` comes from third party library, feel free to use just final version. I just not sure where is the edge of imported functions and your own, hence I wrote/typed everything.

Since we have our main utils setup, we can type our main function:

```js
type GetKeyBaValue<Obj, Value> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends Value ? Prop : never
}[keyof Obj]

type Test = GetKeyBaValue<{ age: 42, name: 'Serhii' }, 42> // age

const mapTyped = <
  Keys extends keyof MappedFunctions,
  Mapper extends <Arg extends Record<string, Keys> | Array<Keys>>(arg: Arg) => Repository
>(mpr: Mapper) => {
  function anonymous<Prop extends string, Mp extends Record<Prop, Keys>>(map: Mp): {
    [P in Keys as GetKeyBaValue<Mp, P>]: MappedFunctions[P]
  }
  function anonymous<Prop extends string, Mp extends Record<Prop, Keys>>(map: Mp) {
    return mpr(map)
  }
  return anonymous
}
```

**`GetKeyBaValue`** - returns `key` by `value`.

As you might have noticed, `mapTypes` is curried function. Furthermore, it returns overloaded function `anonymous`. It is possible to make it `arrow` but then you need to use type assertion `as`. I think that overloading is safer, however it has own drawback because it behaves bivariantly. So it is up to you.

WHole code:

```js
const functions = {
  fooInternal: (fooArg: number) => 1 + fooArg,
  barInternal: (barArg: string) => "barArg: " + barArg,
  bazInternal: (bazArg: boolean) => ["some", "array", "with", bazArg]
} as const

type FunctionsKeys = keyof typeof functions;

type MappedFunctions = {
  fooInternal: (fooArg: number) => number,
  bazInternal: (bazArg: boolean) => (string | boolean)[]
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type MethodType = (...args: any[]) => any;
type Repository = Record<string, MethodType>;

const mapperArray = <Elem extends FunctionsKeys, Elems extends Elem[]>(map: [...Elems]) =>
  map.reduce<Repository>((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: functions[elem]
  }), {})

const mapperObject = <
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  Value extends FunctionsKeys
>(map: Record<Key, Value>) =>
  (Object.entries(map) as Array<[Key, Value]>)
    .reduce<Repository>((acc, elem) => ({
      ...acc,
      [elem[0]]: functions[elem[1]]
    }), {})

const mapper = <Key extends FunctionsKeys>(map: Record<string, Key> | Key[]) =>
  Array.isArray(map)
    ? mapperArray(map)
    : mapperObject(map)

type GetKeyBaValue<Obj, Value> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends Value ? Prop : never
}[keyof Obj]

type Test = GetKeyBaValue<{ age: 42, name: 'Serhii' }, 42> // age

const mapTyped = <
  Keys extends keyof MappedFunctions,
  Mapper extends <Arg extends Record<string, Keys> | Array<Keys>>(arg: Arg) => Repository
>(mpr: Mapper) => {
  function anonymous<Prop extends string, Mp extends Record<Prop, Keys>>(map: Mp): {
    [P in Keys as GetKeyBaValue<Mp, P>]: MappedFunctions[P]
  }
  function anonymous<Prop extends string, Mp extends Record<Prop, Keys>>(map: Mp) {
    return mpr(map)
  }
  return anonymous
}


const methods = {
  ...mapTyped(mapper)({ baz: "bazInternal", foo: "fooInternal" }),
  otherMethod: () => 42
};

methods.baz(true) // ok
methods.foo(42) // ok

methods.otherMethod() // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMKBLcEYF4YG8BQM8IIAkmFAKYBOYAhgDYBcMAFHCQILUDmLYCALYAjGgEpsAPhgBGGAGpiIbjwA0hGMLrVyVWoxast1FS2jVUYHhKzSARMdMw7CzdpXqiWgF66a9ZjYfJ2ESBko6MBtpAG07CBBBSjtVZ21qOgBPFOcAd1QoAAsc4N4AXXwAXxg6TFBIKHx8KEyAB0oYADEkFHRIAGlKTMwcAGshkDgYFvbJ+B60DABuJpmOgFk6VvaAE27kRchsPA0OMgp-AzYzpwERcSkYO9FqTzdfC-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-Ia-GmuahnGSRLDTjQf5LlA1lIu0MAAOI0l6ABCdAIVif6pAh+InK2e4HjAlgwMScx-gxf4xOFrRlBeImYAhMBmUlMD8JQABuNBVESExTHFrkdDimKwDgnlQD5fnojmuA1DwlAsAALAATKk9BJCwADkADKNCFKgqD9TAlSpF10gAPSzS1lATrx5mtAyuwrmuQwBpu27RSVVL8Xs14YG8mzbAJwl7ViKipXtz5KvJFhqjAkmQlBZpZFikkRuyLAqHyWEFkW96Rq01AsOdJp8sR3YemA-LgJkgggAg2LZVdwaqmoVKtHdwYPcqSVKdtkhSdGuNiCwxFhZFCO3jUmC1fV-nrK0qQ7pIDFQxmYm9olg6TacJ0I5ESMo2jWIY7tWMKS9bP45ghNS-u7OvaT5OQ0ZoX1umUAILQhrgy5Q4aHrBui2A4uo3eiLLQ0ho0oUdIjDrcZRutGaGdDtbvCwDi-H4Xw5Gc-tnEHAQuJxGggEUNAas7OyGHyXVVLqSSahAzI+KwwEYhI80wCAoz4BnidZ2crBdQXC3F00Zcu8yseFPHTt0qwNdPEILz4EAA)

Comment: You're a magician! 

Comment: Ended up altering the typed mapper so that it accepts a generic argument, since in my real project I have 20+ different `MappedFunctions` so I have to provide it. See updated question for final code.

Comment: I'm happy that it works for you!