# Either type containing different types

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

**[Original post edited to simplified example]**

I want to create a component that will take one pair of values (both values based on the same type
-> `value`, `setValue`), and, based on it, will run functions depending on those types. To fully illustrate the situation:

AnimalAndCatTypes.ts:

```
export interface Animal {
  type: string,
  age: number
}

export interface Cat extends Animal {
  typeOfCat: string,
}
```

ChangeSpecies.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Animal, Cat } from "./AnimalAndCatTypes";

interface AnimalVersion {
  value: Animal;
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Animal>>;
}

interface CatVersion {
  value: Cat;
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Cat>>;
}

type Props = AnimalVersion | CatVersion;

const ChangeSpecies = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const { value, setValue } = props;

  const handleChange = (data: string) => {
    setValue({ ...value, type: data });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value.type}
          onChange={(data) => handleChange(data.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ChangeSpecies;
```

ExampleComponent.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Animal, Cat } from "./AnimalAndCatTypes";
import ChangeSpecies from "./ChangeSpecies";

const ExampleComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [animal, setAnimal] = useState<Animal>({
    type: "dog",
    age: 2
  });
  const [cat, setCat] = useState<Cat>({
    type: "cat",
    age: 1,
    typeOfCat: "persian"
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ChangeSpecies value={animal} setValue={setAnimal} />
      <ChangeSpecies value={cat} setValue={setCat} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

The problem is in `setValue` where the typescript says that there can't be `Animal` used in `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Cat>>` because of missing `typeOfCat`.

How to create a type in which ts will know that `Props` are either `Cat` or `Animal` when creating component by checking that `value` and `setValue` are from one pair. Later, depending on that pair of types, will take the proper `setValue` type which is linked to `value` type and cannot mix with another?

**[Added in edit]**

Link to reproduction: [https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-mirzakhani-1x4kz?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zealous-mirzakhani-1x4kz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: please share reproducible example

Comment: I believe that this example will show the main problem
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-mirzakhani-1x4kz?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main problem is in this union:

```js
type Props = AnimalVersion | CatVersion
```

Because `Props` is a union, `setValue` is also a union of `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Animal>> | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Cat>>`.

According to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred:

It means, if you want to call such function, arguments of all functions in a union will merge (intersect), that why `setValue` expects `React.SetStateAction<Animal> & React.SetStateAction<Cat>`.

Please see simple example:

```js
declare var foo: (val: { name: string }) => void
declare var bar: (val: { surname: number }) => void

declare var union:typeof foo | typeof bar

// expects { name: string;} & { surname: number; }
union()
```

Most of the time, people are receiving `never`, because of this:

```js
declare var foo: (val:  string) => void
declare var bar: (val:  number ) => void

declare var union:typeof foo | typeof bar

// expects never
union()
```

`string & number` -> produces `never`, because this type is unrepresentable.

In you case, `setValue` expects `Cat`, because `Cat` is a subtype of `Animal`. Intersection of supertype `Animal` and subtype `Cat` - gives you `Cat` type. You have an error, because `setValue` expects `Cat` whereas `props.value` might be an `Animal`, without extra  `typeOfCat` type.

Now, when we know why you are getting intersection, we can proceed.

In order to fix it, you can create extra generic parameter for `Animal|Cat`:

```js
import React from "react";

export interface Animal {
  type: string,
  age: number
}

export interface Cat extends Animal {
  typeOfCat: string,
}


interface AnimalVersion {
  value: Animal;
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Animal>>;
}

interface CatVersion {
  value: Cat;
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Cat>>;
}


type Props<T> = {
  value: T,
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
}


const ChangeSpecies = <T extends Animal | Cat,>(props: Props<T>): JSX.Element => {
  const { value, setValue } = props;

  const handleChange = (data: string) => {
    setValue({ ...value, type: data });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value.type}
          onChange={(data) => handleChange(data.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
};

const jsx = <ChangeSpecies value={{ type: 'animal', age: 42 }} setValue={(elem /** elem is animal */) => {

}} />


const jsx2 = <ChangeSpecies value={{ type: 'animal', age: 42, typeOfCat: 'cat' }} setValue={(elem /**elem is infered as a cat */) => {

}} />

// error
const expectedError = <ChangeSpecies value={{ type: 'animal', typeOfCat: 'cat' }} setValue={(elem ) => {

}} />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCqQA9JY5gA7GJKTdJOAQWdBQAbOAG8qcODACeYJAC44AZxhQWAcwA04uCjXy4zAK4gARuyoBfKjXrR4LNhy5wAwinh02zACaLe-ECFRbWlZAHlMNxgFZVVmTUtrakoHdk40bj4BQQA1dkVgCGZgygkANyFDfSzAwQpSpSQYHMr9ZHQYADoAEWBFMHc0AAsAHnaMToBlJsmYdyQeDELmEZqhAD51%20qtk1KcM13c8qAKikvLWhSj6iUUmlsEqhXGu3v7B0Zepmbm2RZhliMopttkkqKFuAAFHBgRQjAAq6zgAF5znAKo99PCtA07s1LohiK8%20gMYMMxkTvjBZvN-oDEVtEskqGgispXEMUPEkJNZGhgEg-KiEXBPEgfH41sIAD6HGAadYACjAMMUCmhEFhCPWAEoFAApSYADU6AFFBEgQOL4MikWIGqzmOyROjWhpGvjMXALCi4CrNYp6tpHezOT4LS4w3pfYrvO4UDEVOodSi7dpbvdWoqXZ1cxiqu6IQo43NvTqbt6gw0iDBDFBior03ARphoCB1k2JCNBCgzIIOw0JEPmywwIYYJ3h5IZEhkfg2LQYPhJ8P87ORGvOhCdlOp0VI1y9MiRLH4ynbXAw94I1GkKe5luUFA9F01zqd7u4AB6Ae7kZfns%201-Id-1bKB220ctLCrEN4AAK0UWhfSBW9eSQflBVdTFjxdIs4AAci5bJ8PdXR9AAFgAJm9H08QeKpj0VJALTwL8ACo2NFFimD8IjajgNiv3PNNkgsH0fzBShYLgBDaGo4UD25NCML8NccOnWQFEIgIhBInQ9AUKjCxnCIoi0tB3HwmiPXo9cmO49i2OYy0eKYZhMHYJBvB0Xi4As%20BBOEkpLHEgcqC-L9RSgHAoBZNkPHodC2G8U1ougZDFL0ZSBVU1p1Lw7TiOM8JIncczLOsui8pPZy8CC%200Qu-dYgA)

Now, TS is aware that `value` has valid type for `setValue`. SInce, both types have `type` property, this line `setValue({ ...value, type: data });` is valid

However, you should be aware about drawback of this solution:

```js
type Props<T> = {
  value: T,
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
}

type Result = Props<Animal | Cat>

const invalid: Result = {
  value: { type: 'animal', age: 42 },
  setValue: (elem /**React.SetStateAction<Animal | Cat> */) => {

  },
}
```

TS still think that `elem` is a union.

It means that if you provide explicit union generic during component construction:

```js
const jsx = <ChangeSpecies<Animal|Cat> value={{ type: 'animal', age: 42 }} setValue={(elem) => {

}} />
```

TS will allow you to do it.

---

**Second option**

Safer solution is to use [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type Props<T> = T extends any ? {
  value: T,
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
} : never

type Result = Props<Animal | Cat>
```

In fact, this type is equal to your representation of Props union. It just written in more generic way.

If you want to stick with this solution, you should then create [custom typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). It means it will affect your runtime. While, it is possible to write type guard for value, like `isString` or `isNumer`, it is hard to write typeguard for function. Because you can compare functions only by reference or arity.length. Hence, I think, it does not worth it.