# Typescript doesn't infer correct type with conditionals

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inference, conditional-types

I'm using the same type (Options<ST extends SwitchType) for `useStrategy` options parameter and for `toPayload` options one. What I would expect is that Typescript could infer the correct type for `toPayload` options. Instead, it gives me an error message:

> Argument of type 'FirstOptions | SecondOptions' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'FirstOptions'.   Property 'b' is missing in type
> 'SecondOptions' but required in type 'FirstOptions'.(2345)

Is this a known Typescript limit or am I missing something?

```
enum SwitchType {
    First = 'first',
    Second = 'second'
}
export type FirstOptions = {
  a: string
  b: number
}
type SecondOptions = {
    a: string
}

export type Options<ST extends SwitchType> = ST extends SwitchType.Second ? SecondOptions : ST extends SwitchType.First ? FirstOptions : never

type Strategy<ST> = ST extends SwitchType.Second ? SecondStrategy : ST extends SwitchType.First ? FirstStrategy : never

type ToPayloadFunction<ST extends SwitchType> = (
  options: Options<ST>
) => any

type FirstStrategy = {
  toPayload: ToPayloadFunction<SwitchType.First>
}
type SecondStrategy = {
  toPayload: ToPayloadFunction<SwitchType.Second>
}

const getStrategy = <ST extends SwitchType>(type: ST): Strategy<ST> => {

    const firstStrategy: FirstStrategy = {
        toPayload: (options) => {
            console.log(options)
        }
    }

    const secondStrategy: SecondStrategy = {
        toPayload: (options) => {
            console.log(options)
        }
    }

if(type === SwitchType.Second) return secondStrategy as any
    if(type === SwitchType.First) return firstStrategy as any

    throw new Error('error')
}

const useStrategy = <ST extends SwitchType>(type: ST, options: Options<ST>): void => {
    const { toPayload } = getStrategy(type)
// Argument of type 'FirstOptions | SecondOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type //'FirstOptions'.
// Property 'b' is missing in type 'SecondOptions' but required in type 'FirstOptions'
    toPayload(options)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
enum SwitchType {
  First = 'first',
  Second = 'second'
}

export type FirstOptions = {
  a: string
  b: number
}

type SecondOptions = {
  a: string
}

export type Strategy = {
  [SwitchType.Second]: SecondOptions,
  [SwitchType.First]: FirstOptions
}

type StrategyHandlers = {
  [S in keyof Strategy]: {
    toPayload: (options: Strategy[S]) => void
  }
}

const firstStrategy: StrategyHandlers[SwitchType.First] = {
  toPayload: (options) => {
    console.log(options)
  }
}

const secondStrategy: StrategyHandlers[SwitchType.Second] = {
  toPayload: (options) => {
    console.log(options)
  }
}

const STRATEGY: StrategyHandlers = {
  [SwitchType.First]: firstStrategy,
  [SwitchType.Second]: secondStrategy
}


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;


function getStrategy<ST extends SwitchType>(type: ST): UnionToIntersection<Values<StrategyHandlers>>
function getStrategy<ST extends SwitchType>(type: ST) {
  return STRATEGY[type]
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Params = Values<{
  [T in SwitchType]: [T, Strategy[T]]
}>

const useStrategy = ([type, options]: Params): void => {
  const { toPayload } = getStrategy(type)

  toPayload(options)
}
```

`toPayload` - has a type of union of functions which is usually is not wat you expect, this is why you are getting an error. See my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props) for more explanation.

Also, I have removed conditional types, because in this case it is perfectly fine to use strategy pattern without conditionals, just Map data stracture.

Now, `toPayload` is overloaded function which expects either First or Second type of argument.

I can't say that this is 100% safe, because it allows you to do this:

```js
const useStrategy = ([type, options]: Params): void => {
  const { toPayload } = getStrategy(type)

  toPayload({ a: 's' })
}
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966710/how-to-get-concrete-type-from-mapping-variable/68967097#68967097) answer.

The most safer solution would be this:

```js
enum SwitchType {
  First = 'first',
  Second = 'second'
}

export type FirstOptions = {
  a: string
  b: number
}

type SecondOptions = {
  a: string
}

export type Strategy = {
  [SwitchType.Second]: SecondOptions,
  [SwitchType.First]: FirstOptions
}

type StrategyHandlers = {
  [S in keyof Strategy]: {
    toPayload: (options: Strategy[S]) => void
  }
}

const firstStrategy: StrategyHandlers[SwitchType.First] = {
  toPayload: (options) => {
    console.log(options)
  }
}

const secondStrategy: StrategyHandlers[SwitchType.Second] = {
  toPayload: (options) => {
    console.log(options)
  }
}

const STRATEGY: StrategyHandlers = {
  [SwitchType.First]: firstStrategy,
  [SwitchType.Second]: secondStrategy
}

function getStrategy<ST extends SwitchType>(type: ST) {
  return STRATEGY[type].toPayload
}

const first = getStrategy(SwitchType.First)
const second = getStrategy(SwitchType.Second)

first({ a: '', b: 2 })
second({ a: '' })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1p3lW)